# How can I build my website so that new content is loaded via AJAX when a new URL is entered?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, url, single-page-application

I am working on building a *very* small pet project website that I intend to function as a "single-page" site.

The index.php will load, and then when users click something in the side navbar, the appropriate content will be loaded via AJAX. I know how to do this, but I was wondering if there was a way to also change the URL when doing so.

For instance, if someone clicks "contact", I want the contact form to load in the `content` section. But I would also want the URL to say `www.example.com/contact` instead of `www.example.com` or `www.example.com#contact`.

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but any information would be appreciated.

Comment: What server are you using? That's what's going to matter when resolving URLs

Comment: You can edit the `.htaccess` on the server to rewrite urls. `www.example.com/contact` **=>** `www.example.com/index.php?page=contact` and you can use `php` or `ajax` to call `php` for the content.

Comment: I didn't think about the `.htaccess`! I'll give that a try.

Comment: But you also want to use history API to change url locally in browser and not reload new page

Comment: .htaccess has nothing to do with it; you need [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

Comment: @ChrisG without using `.htaccess` for url rewrite you will navigate to the `contact` directory on the server when visiting that url if saved/bookmarked so some sort of url rewrite will be required if you want those new urls to point back to one page/the index.

Comment: @NewToJS I'm perfectly aware of that, however your comment sounded like `.htaccess` would solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @ChrisG this is why i only posted a comment with a suggestion where to start. If i had included each step then i would post as a answer since it would be a solution to the question.